# htaccess RewriteRule for URL shortener

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a working RewriteRule that for example `http://mydomain/stack` rewrites to `decoder.php?decode=stack` and then redirects it to the correct website because `decoder.php` looks up in its database what the redirect should be.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews  
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^phpmyadmin$ phpmyadmin [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w\d-]{1,})$ decoder.php?decode=$1 [L]
```

But now I need "more levels". First I tried with a dot. Eg. `http://mydomain/l1.stack`, but I couldn't get my RewriteRule to work. Anyway: the better approach would be `http://mydomain/l1/stack` to rewrite to `decoder.php?level=l1&decode=stack` or `http://mydomain/a1/wH4tever.` to `decoder.php?level=a1&decode=wH4tever.`. The "levels" that I want should be fixed in the .htaccess, but the "decode" could be any string.

One problem: I don't get any RewriteRule to work with what I want :-(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a simple rule for a single, fixed and literal "level" string "l1":

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^l1/([\w\d-]{1,})$ decoder.php?level=$1&decode=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w\d-]{1,})$ decoder.php?decode=$1 [L]
```

This should do if there are multiple fixed literal "level" strings (here "l1" or "a1")

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(l1|a1)/([\w\d-]{1,})$ decoder.php?level=$1&decode=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w\d-]{1,})$ decoder.php?decode=$1 [L]
```

That would be the generic variant:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([\w\d-]{1,})/([\w\d-]{1,})$ decoder.php?level=$1&decode=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w\d-]{1,})$ decoder.php?decode=$1 [L]
```

Test yourself: [htaccess.madewithlove.com](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=e76b868d-6a23-4b10-bd42-94bf82f61129)

Comment: I only had to change "level=$1decode=$2" to "level=$1&decode=$2" to make it work. So thank you very much! Also the 'test yourself' is a very good website!! I should make some time to learn regex a lot more...

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was an obvious typo. Thanks for pointing that out, I fixed it in the answer.